# Building own print class method - ggplot2

Tags: r

I'm simply trying to build my own print method, based on my class "facet". Now I want to make a specific `ggplot` when calling `print`, but it throws me the error message

> Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class facetindicator

Code

```
print.facet   <- function(x) {

  print("hello") # The print statement gets outputted fine
  ggplot(data = x, aes( x = published, y = SMA90)) + geom_line()

}
```

Running the `ggplot` manually with the same object but without the `class` attribute works just fine. I've must have missed something trivial, what can it be?

Comment: You could delete the class attribute inside your print.facet function. R first checks which class it is in order to know how to plot it, but it does not know how to plot your own class.

Comment: Is there no way around this? Imagine I would use the class method as an extension of ggplot instead.

Comment: If within the function you change the class to data.frame (or whatever was working for you), the plot will work, but it will not have any effect outside the function. The other approach is indeed adding the class method as an extension of ggplot.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the class method as an extension, How exactly could that be done?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_152.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the facet class when you pass the object to ggplot, or, perhaps more elegantly, via a fortify method,

```
fortify.facet <- function(x) {class(x) <- class(x)[-1]; x}

print.facet   <- function(x) {
  ggplot(data = x, aes( x = published, y = SMA90)) + geom_line()
}

d <- data.frame(published=1:10, SMA90=1:10)
class(d) <- c("facet", class(d))

print(d)
```

You could also consider defining `as.data.frame.facet` and/or `autoplot` methods, which may feel more natural.

Comment: I've tried to search for this fortify method, where can I read more about it? Is it linked to the print object, or can I use this procedure when handling other class methods as well?

Comment: apparently fortify is to be deprecated soon, maybe `?autoplot` has useful hints. I believe the procedure is general enough and was recommended for defining custom ggplot methods.